# Run JBOSS EJB in Tomcat Client

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, ejb

I am using an EJB which is running in JBOSS in a TOMCAT client. I have added the required jar files to run the EJB in the client application. But I am getting a marshallException (java.rmi.MarshalException).

Client Program can call the webservice and it returns a proxy. But the Marshaling / Demarshaling performs is not understanding by me. What should I do to run the JBOSS EJB service in a Tomcat Client. I am not allowed to use OpenEJB or Apache TOMEE. I have to use Apache Tomcat 6.0.39.

I am getting

```
Caused by:java.rmi.MarshalException: Failed to communicate.  Problem during marshalling/unmarshalling; nested exception is: 
    java.io.OptionalDataException
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.SocketClientInvoker.transport(SocketClientInvoker.java:306)
    at org.jboss.remoting.RemoteClientInvoker.invoke(RemoteClientInvoker.java:143)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:525)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:488)
    at org.jboss.invocation.unified.interfaces.UnifiedInvokerProxy.invoke(UnifiedInvokerProxy.java:184)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invokeInvoker(InvokerInterceptor.java:365)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invoke(InvokerInterceptor.java:197)
    at org.jboss.proxy.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.proxy.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.jboss.proxy.ejb.HomeInterceptor.invoke(HomeInterceptor.java:184)
    at org.jboss.proxy.ClientContainer.invoke(ClientContainer.java:101)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.create(Unknown Source)
.....
```

Comment: whats the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Caused by:java.rmi.MarshalException: Failed to communicate.  Problem during marshalling/unmarshalling; nested exception is: 
    java.io.OptionalDataException
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.SocketClientInvoker.transport(SocketClientInvoker.java:306)
    at org.jboss.remoting.RemoteClientInvoker.invoke(RemoteClientInvoker.java:143)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:525)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:488)...